# How to extend table border till end of frame, using reportlab platypus?

Tags: python, reportlab, platypus

I am using `ReportLab` platypus to create a pdf for variable length table. My table splits across pages quite well and utilizes frame length appropriately among pages. 
I am using box border for table and am able to draw a box around each of the table split fragment using following style commands.

```
# All
('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1),.5,colors.black),
# top row
('GRID',(0,0),(-1,0),.5,colors.black),
# all columns
('LINEBEFORE',(0,0),(-1,-1),.5,colors.black),
# last column
('LINEAFTER',(-1,0),(-1,-1),.5,colors.black),
# last row of each split portion
('LINEBELOW',(0,'splitlast'),(-1,'splitlast'),.5,colors.black)
```

I want to stretch border of last fragment of table till end of the frame, even if there is no data to fill till the end. Please suggest, how can I do that?